# 411 fatal errors with no code, how do I fix this?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I've been having this Visual Studio error for a while now and all the fixes I've tried do not seem to work. Basically when I create a project, I get 411 fatal errors. I believe something is wrong with my Visual Studio, however I have tried updating and repairing it via the installer, to no avail. I have also tried changing the include additional directories pathway in project settings, however I do not fully understand what I should be linking it to, it might be irrelevant to my error I'm not sure.

I'm running Visual Studio Community 2019 16.8.4 and using Windows 10

The most abundant errors I'm receiving:

> E1696 cannot open source file ""
> E0282 the global scope has no ""
> E0020 identifier "" is undefined

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

[some of the many errors I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBPxk.png)

Comment: You may not have installed the C++ module. When you install Visual Studio, at one point there's a list of modules (like programming languages and such) that you can check to install. The C++ module is not checked by default. Re-run the installer, watch out for this list.

Comment: I did already have the C++ module installed. But I decided to uninstall and then reinstall Visual Studio, making sure to select the C++ module. This fixed the issue and I am now able to code again.